# How To Set SwiftUI Calendar Default Date With Condition?

Tags: swift

Set default calendar date.
If default date is older than 01/01/2021 then use the 01/01/2021, or use the DateComponents(year: -1), to: Date()) as default date.

```
 public var filterSelections: [String: Any] = []

@Published var fromDate: Date =
    Calendar.current.date(byAdding: DateComponents(year: -1), to: Date()) ?? Date(){
        didSet {
            filterSelections.append(anotherDict: [
                                        "fromDate": self.fromDate.dateStringFromSystemDate,
                                        "toDate":self.toDate.dateStringFromSystemDate])
        }
    }
}


func getDefaultFromDate() -> String{
        let strFromDate = "2021-01-01"
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ssZZZ"
        let fromDate = dateFormatter.date(from: strFromDate)
        
        var defaultFromDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: DateComponents(year: -1), to: Date()) ?? Date()
        
        if (defaultFromDate < fromDate ?? Date()){
            defaultFromDate = fromDate ?? Date()
        }
        print("---- \(defaultFromDate) ")
        
        return defaultFromDate.dateStringFromSystemDate
        
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use DateComponents to get 2021-1-1 as a Date and use Calendar to get the date one year ago and then return the max of the two

```
func defaultDate() -> Date? {
    if let firstDayOfYear = DateComponents(calendar: .current,year: 2021, month: 1, day: 1).date,
       let oneYearAgo = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .year, value: -1, to: Date()) {
        return max(firstDayOfYear, oneYearAgo)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: @Published var fromDate: Date =  getDefaultFromDate(){
        didSet {
  .....
        }
    }                                                                         When I try to put the func in the there, I  go this error.       Cannot use instance member 'getDefaultFromDate' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

Comment: That is a completely different question but I suggest you use an `init` to initialise the property.